# How to grant access to a specific IP address that is blocked by GeoIP[country] in nGinx?

Tags: nginx, geoip

Can't find solution how to solve this.
[Here](http://www.howtoforge.com/nginx-how-to-block-visitors-by-country-with-the-geoip-module-debian-ubuntu) is how I blocked an access to the country and at the same time I need to grand access to a specific IP that is from blocked country.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the solution for this problem.

1) in nginx.conf add

```
http {

    geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;

    map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
        default no;
        LV yes; # in my case it is Latvia (allowed country, but all other are not)
    }

    geo $exclusions {

        default 0;

        123.123.123.123 1;  # here comes allowed IP that is in blocked country list

    }

}
```

2) in your vhost configuration server{} container

```
if ($allowed_country = yes) {
    set $exclusions 1;
}


if ($exclusions = "0") {
    return 403;
}
```

The main idea is from [HERE](http://books.google.com/books?id=1Yfn6E-EXB0C&pg=PT200&lpg=PT200&dq=nginx%20allow%20ip%20from%20block%20country&source=bl&ots=6aNofDH94_&sig=Pzc8pXTxpJxAXe_1FA27ymAOODw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vW_DUcfmGbK44APDmYHAAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CIkBEOgBMAk)

Answer (score 3):

**In http block**

```
geoip_country /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;

map "$geoip_country_code:$remote_addr" $allowed_country {
    default yes;
    "~..:10.11.12.13" yes;
    "~..:11.12.13.14" no;
    "~TR:.*" no;
}
```

**In server block**

```
if ($allowed_country = no) {
    return 403;
}
```